# Script Runs on Homepage but not other pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Head scratcher here. I have a script issue where the script is present on all pages but doesn't seem to execute if it's not the homepage.

If you go to :

www.foulplayornot.com and click on Donate Now, the totals and prices change correctly. (apart from styling but that's not important just now).

BUT,

if you access the same campaign through it's permalink http://foulplayornot.com/campaigns/melbourne/, then the totals don't change. The same scripts seem to load on both pages but I can't find out why it doesn't work.

The only difference is that the first one (homepage using Static Campaign php template ), is a featured campaign and the second link is the normal campaign link using single-campaign.php

The custom script for changing the price totals is added to the bottom of campaignify.js, which is enqueued like so (thought maybe there was a conditional for homepage here but seems not ) :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'campaignify-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/campaignify.js', array( 'jquery', 'fancybox' ), 20130603, true );
```

Custom code in campaignify.js with the relevant code at the bottom under /** Modal Prices **/:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    Campaignify.App.init();
    Campaignify.Widgets.init();

    if ( campaignifySettings.page.is_campaign )
        Campaignify.Checkout();

    $( window ).on( 'resize', function() {
        Campaignify.Widgets.resize();

        Campaignify.App.gridify();
    });

    /** Modal prices  **/

    var price;
    var qty;

    price = $('#myContributeSelect').find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
  qty = $('#myContributeQty').find('option:selected').val();
  var totalFormatted = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
  $('#myContributeTotal').html(totalFormatted);
  $('#Itemprice').val(price);

  $('#myContributeQty').on('change', function() {
    qty = $(this).val();
    price = $('#Itemprice').val();
    var totalFormatted = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
    $('#myContributeTotal').html(totalFormatted);
  });

  $('#myContributeSelect').on('change', function() {
    price = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
    qty = $('#myContributeQty').find('option:selected').val();
    $('#Itemprice').val(price);

      var totalFormatted = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
  $('#myContributeTotal').html(totalFormatted);
    });  
});
```

The HTML for this is (edited out some php to make it more readable/ condensed) :

```
    <div class="sqwrap">
      <div class="sizewrap">
        <h5>Size</h5>

        <div class="size">
           <select name="price-option" class="selectStyle" id="myContributeSelect">
               <option name="edd_options[price_id][]" id="%1$s" class="%2$s edd_price_options_input" value="%3$s" data-price="'.$amount.'">'.wpautop( wp_kses_data( $price[ 'name' ] ) ).
               </option>    
           </select>
        </div>

      <div class="quantitywrap">
        <h5>Qty</h5>
          <select name="qty" class="modalquantity" id="myContributeQty">
            <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
          </select> 
          <div class="arrow-down"></div>
          <input type="hidden" name="Itemprice" value="" id="Itemprice">
        </div>

        <div class="totalwrap">
          <h3>Total</h3>
          <div class="wrap_edd_cart_amount">
              <div class="totalborder">
                    <span class="edd_cart_amount" data-subtotal="<?php echo edd_get_cart_total(); ?>" data-total="<?php echo edd_get_cart_total(); ?>">$<span  id="myContributeTotal">0</span>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I've tried disabling all plugins to no avail. Not sure where to go from here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for reading

Comment: You should reformat your post with the code you suspect it contains the issue

Comment: Thanks for the advice Daniel, I've edited it now. New to Stackoverflow!

Comment: I suspect that if the JavaScript works on one page and not the other then there is likely some JavaScript error preventing the execution. But I would suggest to use a JavaScript debugger to put a breakpoint and inspect the execution flow and variables to ensure it does execute and what is the state of the dom when it does. For example perhaps it executed before the HTML elements were actually available. Maybe you could try wrapping all the JS inside a $(function(){/*code here*/})